# Derivative of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I have a fairly basic question that has perplexed me for a few hours now. I am trying to evaluate the derivative of a function $g(t):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as 
\begin{equation}
g(t) = f\left(\mathbf{x} + t(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x})\right)
\end{equation}
where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a multivariable function and $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I found, from a google search, without proof that \begin{equation}g'(t) = (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x})^T \nabla f\left(\mathbf{x} + t(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x})\right) \end{equation}

I haven't been able to prove this on my own. Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  **x**=$(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and **y**=$(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ .
Then : **x** $+ t($**y**-**x**$)=[x_1 + t ( y_1 - x_1 ),...,x_n + t ( y_n - x_n )]$. 
So, $g(t)=f(x_1 + t ( y_1 - x_1 ),...,x_n + t ( y_n - x_n ))$.
 
Define $z_i(t)=x_i+t(y_i-x_i)$.
 So, $g(t)=f(z_1(t),..,z_n(t))$.
 Now, $g'(t)=\sum{\partial f\over \partial z_i} {dz_i\over dt}$ which equals the desired product you have written.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you.